# Passing configured variables to third party makefile with automake

Tags: makefile, cross-compiling, automake, subdirectory

I'm working with a project that is compiled using autotools. It contains an external library that only has a regular Makefile, when I run configure a Makefile from the top-level project is generated which contains recursively calls make on the library and everything works fine.

The problems appear when I try to cross-compile the project. Top level generated Makefile has correct settings (it has them from the configure script), but the library is still compiled with my default gcc and CFLAGS.

Is there a way to pass variables from the generated Makefile to the library?
I was thinking about adding `export` to the end of generated Makefiles, but I can't find how to achieve that with automake.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, so that was easy. `echo 'export' >> project_top/Makefile.in` helped :-)